# How to add +1 to the number?

Tags: .net, razor, umbraco

This code create thumbnails dynamically:

```
@foreach (var image in Umbraco.Field("Photo").ToString().Split(',').Select(x=>Umbraco.Media(int.Parse(x))))
{
    <li slideIndex="0"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
}
```

i need a script to add +1 the [slideIndex], to get this result:

```
<li slideIndex="0"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
<li slideIndex="1"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
<li slideIndex="2"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use a `@for` loop instead of a `@foreach`.

Comment: also you can use a counter

Comment: No, when the foreach repeat the <li> slideIndex="0" dosen't change i need to change the number dynamicly

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it use a simple counter variable.

```
@int i = 0;
@foreach (var image in Umbraco.Field("Photo").ToString().Split(',').Select(x=>Umbraco.Media(int.Parse(x))))
{
    <li slideIndex="@i"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
    i++;
}
```

But you can also solve your problem with a `@for` loop. That is up to you...

Comment: methinks you have a typo `@int i = 0;`  should be `@{int i = 0}`

Answer (score 1):

```
@
{
   int  i = 0;

   foreach (var image in Umbraco.Field("Photo").ToString().Split(',').Select(x=>Umbraco.Media(int.Parse(x))))
  {
     <li slideIndex="@i"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
      i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: how about script counter function?

Comment: I mean using seperate javascript for it,

Comment: I would not use JavaScript for that, because you need to iterate over all `html` elements and set the value. That is to complex for such a simple task. Inline c# is perfect for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant with [Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
@foreach (var image in Umbraco.Field("Photo")
                              .ToString()
                              .Split(',')
                              .Select((x,index)=> new {
                                  index=index, 
                                  media=Umbraco.Media(int.Parse(x))
                              }))
{
    <li slideIndex="@image.index"> <a href="#"><img class="t02" src="image.jpg"></a> </li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 @{
            var countNum = -1;
            }
            @foreach (var image in Umbraco.Field("Photo").ToString().Split(',').Select(x=>Umbraco.Media(int.Parse(x))))
            {
                {
                countNum += 1;
                }


                    <li slideIndex="@countNum"> <a href="#">
                        <img class="t02" src="@image.Url"></a>
                    </li>                               


            }
```

Comment: it same that @BendEg answer

Comment: I got server error with his code! but thanks for him